# Describing the preference of some time period's being closer to another time period that it forgoes

Tags: phrase-requests, time

Just asked this question on "Christianity", but feel asked it in a very awkward way:

> Do we have any evidence that Martin Luther considered some individuals
>   of the Roman Catholic clergy living in some **centuries close to
>   Luther's time (the closer centuries are preferred)** to be the part of
>   the Universal Church?

I am especially concerned about the part in bold. How do I express that with proper English?

After receiving a comment, and an answer, I am thinking to re-write the sentence as the following one:

> Do we have any evidence that Martin Luther considered some individuals of the Roman Catholic clergy living in some **centuries before Luther's time (the latter centuries are preferred)** to be the part of the Universal Church?

Comment: Yes, it is very awkward. Unfortunately, proofreading is off-topic on this site according to the [faq](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I don't know much about Martin Luther, but I do know that it is logically impossible for him to have considered anything about individuals living in the centuries after he did. `centuries before or during Luther's time` perhaps.

Comment: @Robusto He is not asking for people to proofread anything that I can see. Surely a question about how to phrase a question is not off topic.

Comment: The Q. needs improving in many respects. Suggest re-post with corrections. Voting to close. See also FAQ for tips on asking a great question.

Comment: @TLP Pray what's that to do with ELU? That's for writersSE/ religion right?

Comment: @Kris - What do you mean by "Suggest re-post with corrections"? Do you mean I need to edit my question? If yes, then, of course, I don't mind, but I don't know what corrections I need to make. I mean, I simply don't know how to make it correct. Can you, please, give me some clues? What I wrote in this question is the best I could do.

Comment: @TLP - I see. Thank you. Just edited the question using your suggested phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written a long sentence, and so I would suggest making a few other revisions to tighten it up. Maybe something like this:

> Is there any evidence that Martin Luther considered any of the Roman Catholic clergymen who were his contemporaries or who lived in the centuries preceding his own lifetime a part of the Universal Church?

Comment: Thank you. It's a very good way to phrase it, I think. But there is one problem: the fact that I am more after the evidence of those who lived in the time closer to Martin Luther's time is not expressed in it, while it's kind of important to me that that kind of evidence would be considered first.

Comment: Does this work: Is there any evidence that Martin Luther considered any of the Roman Catholic clergymen who lived in the centuries **immediately** preceding his own lifetime, or who were his contemporaries, a part of the Universal Church?

Answer (score 1):

How about "...in the centuries before his time, especially (or particularly) the ***latter***"?